# Comparing two sqlite tables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I have created a database sqlite with two tables.

```
1.Customers

CustomerId Name
---------- -----------
1 Paul Novak
2 Terry Neils
3 Jack Fonda
4 Tom Willis

2. Reservation

Id CustomerId designation
-- ---------- ----------
1 1 manager
2 2 engineer
3 2 software
4 1 clerk
5 3 director
```

Now I need two uitableviews on singleview. And also two uitextfields.

In the first uitable I need customer name. When I click on any name that name should be displayed in uitextfield and in second uitable the values which matches to only customerId which we have selected the name in first table must be displayed in second table.

For example: in the first table, if I select "Paul Novak", then in the second table I need to display only two values "manager" and "clerk", Because this matches with fist table value we selected.

```
-(Question1*)readData1{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement1;
    int rowid1;
    rowid1=[self getRowId1];

    //.......................................TableName................................................. 
    tempQuery=[@"select * from iapp_question where case_id=" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowid1]];
    //}
    ///........................................................................................ 

    const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement1,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
        vt=[[[Question1 alloc]init]autorelease];
        while (sqlite3_step(statement1)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            vt.question=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement1,2)];
        }
    }
    return vt;
}
```

Comment: Can you copy some code it will increase your responses

Comment: Try your Question code is change try it

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be handle this at the object layer and you don't need to go back to database each time. Of course, it's also depends on how much data you wanna load at once.